# What topics come after continuous finance a la Bjork?

Tags: reference-request, books, continuous-time

Ok so I've understood stochastic calculus and continuous finance. Basically, all of Bjork's "Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time".

What books/topics come next? I was thinking of taking a more practical approach by reading Joshi's "C++ design patterns" or maybe "Monte Carlo methods in Financial engineering", but is this a good idea, or is there more theory to learn? If so, from what source?

Comment: Karatsas and Shreve, and Gatheral